# Integrability of $\ker \alpha(X,.)$

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

Let $N^3$  and $M^4$ be Riemannian Manifolds such that $N$ is a submanifold of $M^4$ and $\alpha$ be the second fundamental form of $N$. 
Given a nowhere-vanishing vector field $X \in TN$, is it true that $\ker \alpha(X,.)$ is integrable?  If not, under what conditions is it possible to state that $\ker \alpha(X,.)$ is integrable?

Comment: First of all, you'd better stipulate that $X$ is nowhere-vanishing (which is OK for your $3$-manifold). What is $B^4$ here? Just the $4$-ball? But I assume you intend trivial normal bundle, regardless.

Comment: Actually, I'm dealing with $N$ and $B$ being any Riemannian Manifolds with dimension 3 and 4, respectively. But it's fine to suppose that $X$ is nowhere-vanishing. Thanks, I'll edit.

Comment: I'll change the notation used for the ambient manifold to M

Comment: It would be interesting to get some motivation for this question. Why do you expect it to be integrable?

Comment: Note a basic counterexample: If $X$ is the "standard" vector field $(-x_2,x_1,-x_4,x_3)$ on $S^3\subset\Bbb R^4$, then $\ker\alpha(X,\cdot) = X^\perp$, and this $2$-plane field is very much not integrable.